# CTE recursion in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This in my first query

```
WITH cte_numbers(n, weekday) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        0, 
        DATENAME(DW, 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT         
        n + 1, 
        DATENAME(DW, n + 1)
    FROM    
        cte_numbers
    WHERE 
        n < 6
)
SELECT 
    weekday
FROM 
    cte_numbers;
```

It returns this result:

```
- Monday 
- Tuesday 
- Wednesday 
- Thursday 
- Friday )
- Saturday
```

This is my second query

```
with cte_mounth (n, month) as 
(
    select 
        1, 
        datename(MM, 0)
    union all 
    select 
        n + 1, 
        datename(MM, N + 1)
    from  
        cte_mounth 
    where 
        n < 10
)
select month 
from cte_mounth ;
```

That returns only junuray, but I followed the same implementation. Can you help me please?

Comment: Generally a tally function or calendar table will be far faster than doing rCTE for this particular problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datename()` takes a date as an argument.  So, "1" and "2" and so on get interpreted as dates.  It is not really important what dates.  I would instead suggest that you use:

```
datename(month, datefromparts(2000, n, 1))
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what do you mean. The problem is ine the incrementation. When i select datename(MM, 0) that returns me Junary. I wanna increment it Febrary etc..

Comment: That is what this code does.  You would be rather surprised what "1" and "2" represent as dates.

Comment: @kardousmas , datename() expects date as parameter , when you pass 0 , it is interperted as 1900-Jan-01 , and id you pass 1 , it interperets as 1900-Jan-02 and so on ...

Comment: @kardousmas Try `select Cast( 1 as DateTime );`.